# how to set runtime library to Multithreaded (/MT) in VS2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, runtime, protocol-buffers, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to get Google Protocol Buffers working with an Unreal-Engine-4 project in Visual Studio 2017.

It seems to be more complicated that I expected! I've seen lots of instructions to "change the projects settings on C++ -> code generation to Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)".

I can set this in CMakeList.txt when running a really simple CMake project ( and have got the addressboook example code working ) but can't find the option to do it in the VS2017 GUI when loaded from Unreal.

I can't find the "code generation" settings anywhere.

[image: Project Properties Menu screenshot]

- any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a C++ project with some C++ source files?

Comment: You don't have a C++ project (managed by msbuild), you have an nmake project. All settings are in make files.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, I have 2 projects: A VS2017 project and a CMAke project. When you use Unreal Engine 4 it generates a VS2017 C++ project automatically. I need to add Google Protocol buffers to that project. To test that I'd got the ProtoBuf side working I hand made a very simple , temporary, CMake project to play with. The key to getting that working was adding "set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "/MT")" to CMakeList.txt. I now need to be able to do that to the UE4 generated project to get that to work.

Comment: Thanks @VTT . I didn't appreciate what UE4 was generating. ( My knowledge is Very out of date. )  I'll target my searching in the NMake direction.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: :o) That's the problem : I don't get those options.
I just get Configuration Properties and then General, Debugging, VC++ Directories and NMake.
[1]