# Windows console application error vcruntime140_1.dll not found

Tags: c++

I made a console application in vs 2017, I can't run it on other computers, it gives a dll error

Error:vcruntime140_1.dll not found

Comment: have you ever tried to build a release version?

Comment: yes, but it won't open. Can I make an application that can run on all Windows? is it possible?

Comment: you can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64609544/build-an-exe-that-runs-without-c-redistributable-package

Comment: or you can search run a C++ exe without vc++ redistributable to find what todo

Comment: Consider statically linking the runtime, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398

Comment: Right-click your project in “Solution Explorer”, select “Properties” from the popped menu. Then the “Property Pages” dialog opens.

In the opened “Property Pages” dialog, select “Configuration Properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library” , set its value to “Multi-threaded (/MT)” or “Multi-threaded Debug(/MTd)”.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebuild your application with MT option.
The program build with this option will not depends on crt dll. Because MT option means static link with C runtime library.

This is an example:
[how to set runtime library to Multithreaded (/MT) in VS2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655209/how-to-set-runtime-library-to-multithreaded-mt-in-vs2017)

Answer (score -1):

you can download vcruntime140_1.dll by searching on google, and then after you download vcruntime140_1.dll, copy and paste C: > Windows > SysWOW64 (if you using windows 64 bit)  C: > Windows > System32 (if you using windows 32 bit)